# Testing equality with mocked parameters

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

I've got the following interface + class:

```
public interface IIdentifier
{
    object ID { get; set; }
}
public class IntIdentifier : IIdentifier
{
    public IntIdentifier() { ID = 0; }
    public IntIdentifier(int initialValue) { ID = initialValue; }

    public virtual object ID { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        // snip
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // snip
    }

    public bool Equals(IIdentifier other)
    {
        // snip
    }
}
```

I'm trying to test a second class:

```
public class SampleClass
{
    public SampleClass(IIdentifier a, IIdentifier b)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }

    IIdentifier A { get; set; }
    IIdentifier B { get; set; }

    public bool CheckEqualityEquals()
    {
        return A.Equals(B);
    }
}
```

I want to unit test `SampleClass` (assume that the `Equals` is tested and works) using Rhino Mocks:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestClassPerformingEqualityInternallyWithStubs()
{
    var a = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IIdentifier>();
    var b = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IIdentifier>();

    a.ID = 1;
    b.ID = 1;

    var testEqual = new SampleClass(a, b);

    Assert.IsTrue(testEqual.CheckEqualityEquals());
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestClassPerformingEqualityInternallyWithRealObjects()
{
    var a = new IntIdentifier(1);
    var b = new IntIdentifier(1);

    var testEqual = new SampleClass(a, b);

    Assert.IsTrue(testEqual.CheckEqualityEquals());
}
```

The test using the mocks (`TestClassPerformingEqualityInternallyWithStubs`) fails. The reason why seems simple enough: since the actual objects being passed in to `SampleClass` are `CastleProxy` objects, the `Equals` implementation for `IntIdentifier` won't get called, and we'll get the object equals instead.

How to fix it isn't quite so clear (to me at least). Obviously `TestClassPerformingEqualityInternallyWithRealObjects` executes the desired test, but it's also implicitly testing part of the implementation of `IntIdentifier` as part of the test.

Is there a standard way to deal with these situations? A few thoughts come to mind:

1. Use the actual implementations (smelly)
2. Inject an object that handles equality into `SampleClass` and having the `Equals` method call this object to do the actual comparison (slight code smell - I'm only injecting it in order to support the testing framework)
3. Find some support in Rhino Mocks to support this situation (I've attempted to use Callback, but have been unable to get it working).
4. Find a different mocking framework that handles this scenario

Comment: The presented code is simplified and isolated from a codebase where we are developing new code (`SampleClass`) that needs to work with existing objects (`IIdentifier`, `IntIdentifier`) that are already widely used in existing code. The usage of `Equals` is also much more complicated. It appears in several LINQ conditions and isn't as simple as the presented `CheckEqualityEquals` method.

Comment: Shouldn't the test for CheckEqualityEquals only verify that the Eqauls method is called on the object A with the parameter B. Instead of checking the result of the A.Eqauls(B). You should only test one method, not the behavior of the methods it depends on.

Comment: @jure This is a (vastly) simplified example. I don't care about the 'Equals' method, or whether or not it is actually called. The actual use of it looks more like `IIndex index = engineDescriptor.Indexes.Find(x => x.ID.Equals(sortParameter.IndexID));` From the perspective of my test, I don't care how the comparison is done (or even that it is done). One could argue that I'm integration testing not unit testing, and I wouldn't disagree, but I still need to do the test. We have other unit tests that verify the Equals implementation.

Comment: More incline with what @jure said. There is hardly much behaviour at all hence you don't get much value writing a Unit Test for this. .Equals would always perform the way it suppose to work. If you 'really' want, as  jure said, you can check the .Equals method is called. But that's also not needed IMO.